# What's a reasonable instance where this regex might not catch a webmail referrer in Google Analytics?

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

`^mail\.(.*)?|(.*)?(web|\.)mail(.*)?` is the exact regex I'm looking to scrutinize.

For example,

- e3.mail.yahoo.com
- webmail.example.com
- hotmail.com
- mail.aol.com

etc.

Comment: Is this for getting the referrals from mass-emails you send?

Comment: yes, that's is one example of what it might be used for.

Answer (score 1):

To be totally honest, its a fruitless effort, especially because even if you do manage to somehow do a re-write of all of the email domains that referred people to your site, there are 3 reasons it won't work:

1. You can't possibly account for all of the email domains out there.
2. If the email is hosted on HTTPS, and your pages are HTTP, you won't see a referrer anyways.
3. A very significant portion of the email using population uses non-web mail, like Outlook, Entourage, Mac Mail, iPhone Mail, Blackberry Mail, Android Gmail, to name a few, that never have a referrer.

Instead, if you're looking to segment the referrals of all of email referrals for tracking in Google Analytics, you should use utm variables in your URLs.

If you tag your URLs with `utm_source` and `utm_medium`, you'll be able to track them, regardless of the 3 restrictions listed above.

Traditionally, you'd set `utm_medium` to be email, and `utm_source` to be the mailing list name, and `utm_campaign` for the name of the specific campaign.

You can get assistance in building the URLs here: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55578

Comment: Yahelc, point #3 is interesting in that case. In Google Analytics, people who click links while in Outlook would just look like Direct visitors then, instead of Referring Site traffic, right? So that's why you'd recommend always using URL tracking variable to automatically set that type of visit to specific source / medium. That makes sense.

Comment: So, if dealing with someone who refuses to implement URL tracking (for example, using the Google URL Builder), what would you suggest? Would you still try to at least filter some of the biggest problem webmail referrera like yahoo mail?

Comment: @Scott Re: case #3, yes, but that's also how it'll appear for #2, and there's absolutely no way to differentiate amongst various direct traffic. There's no 'better' way than URL tracking, unfortunately, at least not for Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Even if **links in email messages should be tagged** with `utm_xxx` parameters, I like to clean and group my referral sources into clusters as much as possible. It is the way to go to understand effectively the sources of traffic that are missing proper tagging, and then prioritize and fix them.

The regex I use is the following, and honestly it works pretty well (it catches more than 95% of webmails that show up as referrals and can be split over dozens of subdomains like for yahoo or live, thus diluting their visibility as a source)

```
(messag|courrier|zimbra|imp|mail)(.*)\.(.*)\..{2,4}
```

You may update the subdomain names with values frequent in your area. The end catches any domain using a tld of 2-4 chars, and any domain.
I output the result as

```
Output To -> Constructor : Campaign Source : Webmail - $A3
```

Comment: @Open_SEO, this looks like a good way to clean up and cluster the sources as much as possible when proper URL tagging is missing. Thanks!